# Create a local notification without the app name

Tags: iphone, ios, notifications, uilocalnotification

The normal format for a local notification is two lines. The app name is on the first line, and the notification's `alertBody` is on the second line.

[image]

The Reminders app has a different style, not showing the app name. Or rather, instead of the app name, the alert body is the only thing shown, and it's in bold.

[image]

Is it possible to get this style or is it an Apple-only thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This cannot be done (without accessing private API's). This is to prevent applications pretending to be other applications. Only Apple applications are able to hide the title.